# SQL Server 2014 Installation Error

Tags: sql-server, installation

I can't install SQL Server 2014 for my laptop.It has minimum requirements

- 4gb Ram
- 500gb Hard Disk
- i3 Processor
- Os Windows 8.1

Error:

> The operating system on this computer or its service pack level does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL Server 2014. To determine the minimum required operating system supported for this SQL Server release, see hardware and software requirements for installing SQL Server 2014

I have already checked "Compatibility Settings" tab on properties. Run as administrator. Remove tick marks/assigned tick marks. But same error occurs.

What should I do? I can't understand official linked solutions. Can anyone tell me what I should do please? Any other settings?

Note: operating system is 64 bit. I have tried x86, x64 and both met with this error.

Comment: What *edition* are you trying to install (e.g. Standard, Developer, Express, etc)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It is Express. It is finely work with windows 8.1 But not in windows 7